# Error sending transaction to the First Blood crowd sale contract

Tags: transactions, presale

I have sent ether to **First Blood** crowd sale but have an error message:

> Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad jump destination]

I don't know what to do, please advice me.

Comment: Now you can buy First Blood tokens from an exchange like yunbi.com

Answer (score 4):

## Summary

The reason why you got the error message is because the crowd sale has ended as the funds raised reached the maximum cap of 465,313 ethers within minutes after the crowd sale commenced.

As `@eth` commented below, any transactions sent to this contract after the crowd sale has ended will end up with an error, and your funds don't leave your account. You will however have to pay some gas for the cost of this error transaction. This amounts to a few cents, depending on the gas parameter sent with your transaction.

See [When can First Blood 1ST tokens be transferred?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9145/when-can-first-blood-1st-tokens-be-transferred) for the estimated time when 1ST tokens can first be transferred. This date is Dec 23 2016. Trading of 1ST tokens has already been enabled at Yunbi and Gatecoin.

## Details

The crowd sale contract was deployed with the following parameters:

- Starting block `startBlock` = 2327212
- Ending block `endBlock` = 2500012
- Maximums ethers to be raised `etherCap` = 465313000000000000000000 or 465,313 ETH

The [first valid crowd sale transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5643755619e61e864b57be049b0921737070966765325eaaf0c017b98c5bb1b9) occurred in block [2327214](https://etherscan.io/block/2327214) at Sep-25-2016 11:55:33 PM +UTC.

The [last crowd sale transaction with value >= 1 ETH](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x30bd5b485c314faad4e9b823ca86eaf0d986bc71a885a0599f9d59b6d2bc7eea) occurred in block [2327255](https://etherscan.io/block/2327255) at Sep-26-2016 12:04:21 AM +UTC, around 9 minutes from the crowd sale commencement.

The [final crowd sale transaction with value 0.026 ETH](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x656331405c6c06606e0625cd5b30aee9b63d734775699f09d3544e8bd0b27566) occurred in block [2327898](https://etherscan.io/block/2327898) at Sep-26-2016 02:38:30 AM +UTC, around 4.5 hours from the crowd sale commencement.

You can see the crowd sale funding account at [0xa5384627f6dcd3440298e2d8b0da9d5f0fcbcef7](https://etherscan.io/address/0xa5384627f6dcd3440298e2d8b0da9d5f0fcbcef7#internaltx), with a balance of 465,313.08947415 Ether ($5,686,125.95).

Here are the variables from the First Blood crowd sale contract at [0xaf30d2a7e90d7dc361c8c4585e9bb7d2f6f15bc7](https://etherscan.io/address/0xaf30d2a7e90d7dc361c8c4585e9bb7d2f6f15bc7#readContract):

[image]

You can view the source code for the crowd sale contract at [0xaf30d2a7e90d7dc361c8c4585e9bb7d2f6f15bc7#code](https://etherscan.io/address/0xaf30d2a7e90d7dc361c8c4585e9bb7d2f6f15bc7#code).

Here is an article describing the crowd sale that ended in minutes - [Decentralized eSports Platform FirstBlood Raises $5.5M in Minutes](https://news.bitcoin.com/esports-firstblood-raises-5-5m/).

Comment: Thank you. So how can I get refunded please? or will they give me in tokens in future?

Comment: You don't need a refund because the error reverts the transaction, meaning that the ether never left your account.

Comment: Okay thanks again, very strange but exchange has taken from my wallet. I will contact them.