# When can First Blood 1ST tokens be transferred?

Tags: transactions, tokens, wallet-transfer

This question was prompted by the reddit question [Why have all 1ST token transactions an error?](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/56mlpl/why_have_all_1st_token_transactions_an_error/) and [Error sending transaction to the First Blood crowd sale contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9121/error-sending-transaction-to-the-first-blood-crowd-sale-contract).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Summary

1ST tokens can be transferred after block 2,870,297, estimated to be Dec 23 2016, just in time for Christmas.

## Details

Here are the variables from the First Blood crowd sale contract at [0xaf30d2a7e90d7dc361c8c4585e9bb7d2f6f15bc7](https://etherscan.io/address/0xaf30d2a7e90d7dc361c8c4585e9bb7d2f6f15bc7#readContract):
[image]

In particular, note the following parameters:

- Ending block `endBlock` = 2500012
- Transfer lockup period `transferLockup` = 370285

From the [First Blood crowd sale contract source code](https://etherscan.io/address/0xaf30d2a7e90d7dc361c8c4585e9bb7d2f6f15bc7#code):

```
/**
 * ERC 20 Standard Token interface transfer function
 *
 * Prevent transfers until freeze period is over.
 *
 * Applicable tests:
 *
 * - Test restricted early transfer
 * - Test transfer after restricted period
 */
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
    if (block.number <= endBlock + transferLockup && msg.sender!=founder) throw;
    return super.transfer(_to, _value);
}
```

Transfers will only be enabled after the block number exceeds `endBlock + transferLockup` or `2,500,012 + 370,285 = 2,870,297`.

The latest block [2,410,803](https://etherscan.io/block/2410803) has a timestamp of Oct-09-2016 09:30:52 PM +UTC.

We will need to wait `2,870,297 - 2,410,803 = 459,494` blocks before the transfer is enabled. This will take `459,494 x 14 / 60 / 60 / 24 = 74.45` days assuming a 14 second average blocktime.

The estimated date when transfer is enabled is Dec 23 2016.

Until then, all transfer transaction will generate a Bad jump destination as encountered in the following [transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x841c61c910b81e52fb7d4570a50ddf739c8170ffdddcf0a4427d80362a6d8626):
[image]

In the meantime, only the contract owner (`founder`) can transfer the tokens. Trading of 1ST tokens has already been enabled at Yunbi and Gatecoin - see [Coin Market Cap - 1ST](https://coinmarketcap.com/assets/first-blood/#markets).